# px unit for flex-basis value gets truncated after webpack build

Tags: webpack, less-loader

I have the following code in my less file:

```
flex: 1 0 0px
```

I should put 'px' unit for flex-basis due to its bug in Internet Explorer.
However, after webpack build, 'px' unit gets truncated. The css output has the following line:

```
flex: 1 0 0
```

Is there any way to prevent this? As a workaround solution, I can split this one line into three using flex-grow, flex-shink and flex-basis.